# jquery libraries

Tags: jquery, libraries

What is the difference between all jquery libraries?

If I download plugin of jquery-1.2.6.min.js and plugin of jquery-1.4.2.js, can't I combine them at the same page? Is there a way to avoid crash betwwen the libraries so both plugin will work?

For instance, Firebug returns this error when trying to combine plugins from different  libraries

```
jQuery is not defined 
(jQuery);"
```

or

```
$ is not defined 
$(function(){
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you need two versions of jQuery?  Try to find newer versions of the plugins that all work with the same (and maybe the newest) version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

here you have a link that could be very helfull. Jquery has a new plugin called noconflict and here you have the tutorial to learn to use it.

http://drupal.org/node/578712

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict()` has been part of jQuery core (rather than being a plugin) since 1.0 (2006) - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

`jquery-1.2.6.min.js` is version 1.2.6 of jQuery and has been minimized.

`jquery-1.4.2.js` is version 1.4.2 of jQuery and has not been minimized.

I'm not sure why you'd want to combine the 2 libraries. It's like trying to use Window XP and Windows 7 at the same time (I'm not talking virtual machines). Just use the latest version.

Anyway, the `*.min.js` is an [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) version of the jQuery source code. When you look at it, it won't make any sense to you... it has been compressed.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define JQuery twice on the same page.  The newer version have different functionalties and general updates.  There is almost absolutely no reason to have two versions of JQuery on one page.  You can redefine one of the libaries to use say two dollar signs instead of one.  The only reason you put two versions of JQuery on a page is two use functionalties from two different versions for say backwards compatibility, but that case it's better to just update your code to work with the newest version.

Comment: we all uses plugins,not always we have the time or the knowledge to change the code,so trying to combine two different plugins sometime demand two different libraries